# WiX installer - environment variables do not expand %APPDATA%

Tags: windows, wix, environment-variables

In a .wxs file I have:

```
<Environment Name="PATH" ... Value="%APPDATA%\Python\Scripts" system="no"/>
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to work. After installing the installer on another machine, I do see that '%APPDATA%\Python\Scripts' is contained in the PATH environment variable. But typing 'foo' (where foo.exe exists in that set path) prints `command not found`.

What exactly went wrong here? Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like [a bug](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/329308) in Microsoft Windows:

```
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/329308
```

Yet, there is no workaround from the WiX side.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the cmd.exe gets updated unless you recycle them. I've also seen the environment get stuck until logoff. Seems to be more of a Windows behavior than anything else. The Windows Installer does send the message to say the environment was updated... I just haven't seen it work all the time.

Comment: What do you mean by 'recycle them'? I am aware that .. for the environment change to take effect, I just have to relaunch cmd.exe (not restart/relogon Windows).

Comment: Actually, restarting the computer fixes it.

Comment: Restarting the computer doesn't fix it sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're updating environment variables and want them available immediately for your applications, then best solution here is to use `ScheduleReboot` element to prompt the user to restart post-install.

It seems like a bit of overkill just to update an environment variable, but it will do the trick.